# how to use mysql command in ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to import a sql file using command line: `mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASENAME < FILENAME.sql`,
but I am not familiar with mysql command line.
I use ssh to connect to server, after connected, it shows: `[tamp@need ~]$`, i input `mysql`, it shows: `-bash: mysql: command not found`,
so what is the problem? what should I do?

Comment: are you sure that mysql is installed on that server? or that is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like mysql client is not installed on the server (or at least its binary is not in the right PATH); you should ask the system administrator to install it. If you're the administrator, well.. you should install it by your own, depending on which OS is installed on the host, you'd need a different procedure. For example, on debian based system you likely would run:

```
apt-get install mysql
```

Comment: +1 with `sudo` if he isn't logged in as root, assuming that his user has sudo privileges

Comment: you're right, I omitted the privileges part for the lack of information we have about his server, I included that in the "you're the administrator" assumption :)

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that MySQL Client program are not installed in your machine.
You can install MySQL client by:

```
$ yum install mysql
```

OR

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have 2 options.

Either connect to your distant server using `ssh` -- then execute remotely `mysql` CLI on the *server*. That's what you have tried so far. But as other have already mentioned it, the `mysql` client doesn't seems to be present there.

The second option is to run `mysql` CLI on your *local* machine and connect it to your *remote* database server.

```
# Assuming your DB server has the DNS name "my-sql-server.home.local":
local-machine$ mysql -u user -h my-sql-server.home.local -p

# or

# Assuming you access your DB server by its IPv4 address "192.168.0.10"
local-machine$ mysql -u user -h 192.168.0.10 -p
```

Please note that, depending your `mysql-server` setup and your security policy the access may or may not be granted.